# How can I exclude an element from a mouseover event with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom, event-handling, dom-events

I'm basically trying to build the equivalent of the firebug inspector in the browser. I'm currently using the `<body>` as the container in this example:

```
container.onmouseover = function(ev) { inspect(ev.target); }
```

In the inspect method, I reposition and resize a semi-transparent fixed positioned element over the element returned from the event target. But this causes the `mouseover` event to subsequently inspect the overlay element itself.

I basically want the event handler to disregard the overlaid element completely (it only exists to provide visual feedback) and continue to fire `onmouseover` events for the elements detected beneath it. Does this make sense?

Comment: is this question related to event bubbling?

Comment: @PaulNikonowicz yes I think so. I wanted the element to be excluded from the event chain. Mr. T Sherman's answer achieves this with CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't have to support all browsers then you could use the css property [pointer-events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/pointer-events). When set to none all events will be ignored. Try toggling pointer-events in this fiddle and see what I mean.

http://jsfiddle.net/zDygA/

[Browser support](http://caniuse.com/pointer-events)

```
pointer-events:none;
```

I hate to link out, but this is a good article if you need to support IE.

http://www.vinylfox.com/forwarding-mouse-events-through-layers/

Comment: Fantastic! That was exactly what I wanted to achieve.

Comment: if i have anchor? it won't work with that solution